# Why is "devano" the third plural person of the verb "dovere" in the subjunctive considered wrong?

Tags: verbs, grammar, subjunctive-mood

In one of my compositions I wrote the following sentence:

> Alla fine, lo scrittore dell'articolo crede che il ministero della salute e l'Alfa **devano** informare i consumatori.

My teacher considered "devano" a mistake and corrected it by using the second form "debbano". Why is it a mistake although both forms are found in my grammar books?

> **presente (Congiuntivo)** 
>  
>   io  deva, debba 
>   tu  deva, debba 
>  
>   lui, lei, Lei, egli deva, debba 
>  
>   noi dobbiamo 
>   voi dobbiate 
>  
>   loro, Loro, essi devano, debbano

Comment: As an Italian, it's a rare, old-fashioned form, and I myself had to check whether it was recorded in a dictionary. So, yes, it's technically admissible but nowadays it sounds quite strange. Presumably your teacher aim at teaching you contemporary, usual Italian.

Comment: @DaG: Can you write this as an anwser, please?

Comment: Ok, @Charo, but I'm open to some more complete answers.

Answer (score 5):

As an Italian, *devano* is a rare, old-fashioned form, and I myself had to check whether it was recorded in a dictionary. So, yes, it's technically admissible but nowadays it sounds quite unusual. Presumably, your teacher aims at teaching you contemporary, usual Italian.

As an illustration, here is a graph comparing the occurrences of *debbano* and *devano* in Google Books Ngram Viewer corpus from 1800 to 2000:

[image]

[Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debbano%2Cdevano&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdebbano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevano%3B%2Cc0)

(*Debbano* itself appears to be declining: this is possibly due to a general decline in the use of the subjunctive mood in some registers of Italian.)